# ggplot trend line is flat

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a trend line along with a 95% confidence interval for my data in [this csv file](http://ww1.speedy.sh/?subid1=65b0b8d8-da5b-11e9-9106-78654072ca83). When I issue this command:

```
ggplot(trimmed_data, aes(x=week, y=V4)) + 
                     geom_smooth(fill='blue', alpha=.2, color='blue')
```

I get this plot, which is great:

[image: plot]

However, when I use the `since_weeks` column (which is the correct one I'd like to use), I get a flat line:

```
ggplot(trimmed_data, aes(x=since_weeks, y=V4)) + 
                     geom_smooth(fill='blue', alpha=.2, color='blue')
```

[image: plot]

the `weeks` column has a range of 0-51, while the `since_weeks` column has a range of 1-52.  Essentially I'm just re-ordering the rows.

I get this warning with both plots:

> geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is >=1000, so using gam with formula: y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"). Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.

Comment: From downloading your data it basically looks like there actually is no trend of V4 based on `since_weeks`- at least not one that the generalized additive model smoother can detect. (I'd be a bit skeptical of the trend line with week on the x-axis as well- notice it stays entirely between .53 and .535, and that the confidence interval is almost entirely as wide as the curve's range)

Comment: To explain further: a `gam` smoother has to choose a number of degrees of freedom to allow for smoothing. If there is no apparent trend, it is possible it will choose just 2 degrees of freedom- a straight line- and it could fit it to then be flat.

Comment: ...also note that you can make the second one more "wiggly" via `geom_smooth(formula = y ~ s(x,k = 20),method = "gam",fill='blue', alpha=.2, color='blue')`, but it is important to note here that at this point one should probably be reading the `gam` and `choose.k` documentation pretty carefully, as well as building an understanding of what the smoother is actually doing, rather than just relying on ggplot's defaults to guess "right".